# CAN line collision detection with XOR gate

Tags: can

I want to connect multiple devices via UART but want to benefit from CAN physical layer its noise resistance and mutlimaster capability. Also I need to detect whether or not there is collision on the line and if so cancel my outgoing transmission. I have figured out that I can achieve this by simply adding XOR gate between RX and TX lines between CAN transceiver and uC. But after looking into some datasheet data it comes with a problem: XOR's propagation delay is up to 10ns (worst case scenario) and CAN transceiver's propagation delay form TX to RX is ~200ns which would result in generating false collision detection signals when transmitting data while the line was idle. What should I do in such a case? I can see 3 possibilities but I am not fully convinced to any of them (maybe there is a better solution):

1. delay TX input of XOR gate with simple RC low pass filter tuned to match CAN transceiver's propagation delay.
2. delay output signal of XOR gate with simple RC low pass filter to filter out spikes shorter than CAN transceiver's propagation delay.
3. Use some hardware in uC to digital filter short spikes on collision detection input.

Comment: So why does it need a XOR gate, why can't you just check if received data matched transmitted data?

Comment: Because I use UART transmitter which only allows me to check byte by byte and not bit by bit

Comment: Yes so if collisions happen the byte received won't match byte sent?

Comment: CAN doesn't have collisions and CAN controller hardware automatically stops transmitting in case someone with higher priority already got the bus. What is the reason why you need to check for this? Is it a real-time requirement or do you expect several frames with same CAN id to get sent at the same time etc?

Comment: I use only CAN physical layer and not full controller.

Comment: Ok. Switching to real CAN would make all your problems go away then... so why don't you?

Comment: Simply component costs.

Comment: And how is adding an extra XOR gate making your BOM cheaper? Needless to say, you'd pick a MCU with a built-in CAN controller. External CAN controllers is a thing of the past.

Comment: extra XOR gate costs below 0.1$. Additional CAN controller in MCU cost much more. Besides that I didn't mention about external CAN controller but transceiver which makes huge difference because there are few MCUs with build in CAN transceiver.

Comment: Components have to be assembled, you can't just look at component cost... assembly contractors typically charge for both rigging pick & place cost + the number of components. And you can even get some MCUs with built-in transceiver + controller both, though they are a bit rare still.

Comment: Anyway, I just realized that what you might actually asking for is [LIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_Interconnect_Network). It isn't "UART over CAN lines", but rather "CAN over UART lines". Otherwise, the standard way to improve UART safety is to go with RS-422/RS-485.